# No more than 26 <audio> items work in my Polymer iron-list of 100 JSON instances

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Me: Code writer level 4 in a 1-10 scale.

None of the **audio** tags with an index greater than '25' seem to work in my iron-list. I have a **paper-icon-button** firing **on-Tap="_playing"** for each template instance in order to make it's corresponding song play by using **currentSound.play();** and it works but only for songs 0-25.

I suspect it has to do with what the [iron-list docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list) say. "only' a small subset of actual template elements (enough to fill the viewport) are rendered and reused as the user scrolls". But I've been at it for over 7 hrs :( with no luck.

If you have a look at the image in the link, you'll notice I added the **controls** attribute to the **audio** tag. An interesting point to note is that all 100 songs can be played, paused and all, using these native controls, however I'm only using these to test things out as all buttons are intended to be customized.

I looked into finding whatever accessibility these native html controls have but found nothing. I also tried understanding **models** in a **dom-repeat** template but couldn't get around it either. Help! I need somebooooody Help! :P

[same image here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5QpOZNj7AlOHp5RGU0T3ZVTTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just to eliminate some issues. If you resize your windows height, will it work with less songs (for example 0-15 instead)? Or in other words; if you print out the `index` to the console, what does it say when you press the 26th element?

Comment: yup "index" prints out 0-100 correctly. And on the 26th element, it shows "26" but doesn't play the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found the issue (I think)!

You need to change your method `_playing` to this:

```
_playing: function(item)
{
   var parentNode = Polymer.dom(item.target).parentNode;
   var currentSound = Polymer.dom(parentNode).querySelector(".theSound");
   currentSound.play();
}
```

So what was wrong with your first solution?

When you write: `document.getElementsByClassName("theSound")` it will return all your elements with the class `theSound` that is currently ***visible*** (which is a specific behaviour for `iron-list`, see Dogs comment for details), meaning you won't get the 26th element. If you scroll down and that code is ran, it will still only return 25 elements (for example 5-30), but they will still be indexed in the array as 0-25. So when you press the 30th element, you will try to access element 30, when it's actually at position 25 in the array.

My solution eliminates this by not relying on the index. What I do is I pick the `parentNode` of the item being pressed and then I search for the element with the class `theSound` *within* that node, and thus it will only return one item (in the row that you pressed).

Comment: Just to try to clarify this to avoid confusing people, document.getElementsByClassName is not going to restrict to visible elements in general. This is specific to iron-list. What's happening in iron-list is that it is creating only enough elements to fill the visible space, and swapping out which backing model is being provided to those elements. So while there may be hundreds of elements in the list, there will only be a handful of them in the document. This answer is definitely correct, I just didn't want the 'only visible elements' part to confuse people.

Comment: Great, this seems like the solution. It's pretty new to me but I'm reading all about the Polymer DOM API. However, since I have more html elements throughout the file, I'm not sure if the code is selecting the correct ones. 

What does Polymer.dom(item.target).parentNode; select? The <paper-iron-icon> button? or the <template> element? Not sure. 

By the by, how can I see what I'm selecting with Polymer.dom?  =S  thanks guys!

Comment: `item.target` will return the html-element that is being pressed (the one in which your `on-tap` is located). In your case, it will return `paper-icon-button`. `parentNode` will return the element-node which is the parent, I'm not sure which one that is, because you didn't include all your code. But I would suggest you wrap your "row"-content in a div so that your `parentNode` will be correct.

Comment: Howdy... it's been a while but I'd like to clarify that user2422321's solution above is completely correct. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks for the help. I think I found the problem! I found that in `<style>` `host: { position: absolute }` causes songs 0-25 to repeat 4 times up to 100 instead of continuing with 26-100. I removed it, and all 100 songs play correctly now.

Then, I tried the using:

`Polymer.dom(item.target).parentNode;  & 
    Polymer.dom(parentNode).querySelector(".theSound");`

but couldn't make it my select .theSound. Then I tried `document.getElementsByClassName("theSound")[index];` and POOFF like magic! everything works now hoorraaaay

Problem: `position: absolute` on the host styling was making things whacky.
Solution: move `position: absolute` to the toolbar styling

Comment: I'm skeptical to your approach. If `document.getElementsByClassName("theSound")[index]` actually works, that should mean that your `iron-list` isn't working as intended (all of the elements shouldn't exist unless they are all visible at the same time).

Comment: To be sincere, I'm not 100% sure why things work. ahhhhh I'm a newbee! But I'll continue trying to work it out with your method. I just can't seem to make 
'var parentNode = Polymer.dom(item.target).parentNode;
   var currentSound = Polymer.dom(parentNode).querySelector(".theSound");' select the correct nodes to trigger the audio. Just a matter of trying harder tho. Will get back